# Difference between Mono/Flux.fromCallable and Mono.defer

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor

I usually have the requirement of generating a Mono/Flux whose values will be generated/calculated on subscription time. For this both fromCallable and defer operators seem to be fine.

I can´t see the difference clearly in the javadoc:

**FromCallable:**

> public static  Mono fromCallable(Callable supplier)
>
> Create a Mono producing its value using the provided Callable. If the
>   Callable resolves to null, the resulting Mono completes empty.

**Defer**:

> public static  Mono defer(Supplier>
>   supplier)
>
> Create a Mono provider that will supply a target Mono to subscribe to
>   for each Subscriber downstream.

Could you explain if both can be used for this requirement and what exact difference there is between them?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`Mono.defer` is usually used when you already have a `Mono` from a third-party source, but you want to delay its creation until subscription time because during its creation something is done eagerly.

Consider the following example:

```java
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    callExternalService()
            .repeat(3)
            .subscribe();
}

private static Mono<?> callExternalService()
{
    System.out.println("External service is called.");

    return Mono.just("result");
}
```

At first glance, you'd think this example has no issues but when you check the output, you can see that `External service is called` is only printed once instead of the expected four (one original + three repeats) because it is executed outside of the scope of the returned `Mono`.

However, if you `defer` the execution of the `Mono`, it will be printed four times as expected:

```java
Mono.defer(() -> callExternalService())
    .repeat(3)
    .subscribe();
```

Another use case for `defer` is when you want to test a repeat/retry/re-subscribe logic and you want to have different return values for the mocked service which returns the `Mono`.

In conclusion, it is indeed very similar to `fromCallable`, but mostly used when you already have a method which returns a `Mono` and does something eager. If you have complete control over the code, then you are completely fine with `fromCallable`.