# What is the real world case for Mono.defer()?

Tags: java, reactive-programming, reactor, reactive-streams

I know what `Mono.defer()` does do, but when should I use it? I know that one of the use cases is to defer some blocking side effects in functions that return `Mono`, but that's generally a bad practice (putting side effects in functions that return `Mono` or `Flux`). And when I want to wrap some blocking code within the `Mono` there's `Mono.fromCallable()`. So what is the best case to use `Mono.defer()`?

Comment: RX calls it "cold" observables

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between Mono/Flux.fromCallable and Mono.defer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60077499/difference-between-mono-flux-fromcallable-and-mono-defer)

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you need to calculate something synchronous lazily.

For instance, we have an asynchronous service

```
public interface SomeService {

    Mono<User> getUserByName(String name);

    Mono<CreateUserResult> createUser(User user);

}
```

and an endpoint, which looks up for the user in this service and creates if the one was not found. BUT before the creation some heavy calculations must be performed in sync in special thread pool. So

```
someService.getUserByName(name)
                .switchIfEmpty(Mono.defer(() -> {
                    var someHeavyCalculatedData = localHeavyService.doSomethingNecessary(name);
                    return someService.createUser(new User(name, someHeavyCalculatedData));
                }).subscribeOn(specialScheduler));
```

Sure, you can say that we can use `Mono.fromCallable` instead and do it like

```
someService.getUserByName(name)
                .switchIfEmpty(Mono.fromCallable(() -> localHeavyService.doSomethingNecessary(name))
                        .subscribeOn(specialScheduler)
                        .flatMap(someHeavyCalculatedData -> someService.createUser(new User(name, someHeavyCalculatedData)))
                );
```

But each method call in reactive chain causes creation of a huge amount of objects in memory. Well for one single call you, probably won't notice anything, but with higher load frequent allocating memory, then releasing it by GC would cause your app being slow.

Answer (score 0):

`Mono.fromCallable()` is for regular deferred service call. The `Mono.defer()` produces a `Mono` and it does that only when you *subscribe*. So, you may decide to create this or that `Mono` not during composition phase, but exactly on the target subscribe.

Comment: I understand that, but why would I need that? What's the use case?

Comment: When you need to create a `Mono` not immediately as it is with `Mono.just()`, but later, only when subscribe happens and the result may depend on that subscriber context. For example you need to propagate a security context which really depend on the authenticated subscriber.

Answer (score 0):

**`@a.khakh`**

A very simple use case that helped me was to execute blocking code in another thread, that is, to process that blocking call so that the main-thread would not block me.

I saw the need to use defer to subscribe in another thread, in this case in a Scheduler provided by project reactor and programmed by Simon Basle.

- [source using Mono.defer](https://github.com/rucko24/poc-sync-asyn/blob/main/src/main/java/com/simulation/syncvsasync/views/helloworld/SyncVsAsync.java#L97)

If you do a combination of `defer` plus `subscribeOn` and a `Schedulers.boundedElastic` you will make your code non-blocking or rather it will not **block** your application, removing contention in Reactor's default Scheduler at that time, perhaps Schedulers.parallel

---

The following image shows that the third component of a Combo, internally uses a defer plus a Scheduler, so as not to block the application.

[image]

- ignore the method called `ui.access()` it is part of the vaadin framework.

```java
Mono.defer(() -> this.reactiveRandomNumbers.monoFrecuency(event.getValue().getSize()))
                        .doOnEach(signal -> log.info("Thread name doOnNext(): {}", Thread.currentThread().getName()))
                        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
                        .subscribe(subscribeMap -> {
                            ui.access(() -> {
                                log.info("Thread name subscribe(): {}", Thread.currentThread().getName());
                                this.execute(event.getValue().getSize(), e -> subscribeMap);
                            });
                        });
```

Comment: So, what is the blocking code in your case? `SECURE_RANDOM.ints`?

Comment: Yes, it is executed in the main-thread and if you execute Blockhound you can see that inside a blocking call is made and it detects it. 

Has the method that I put you above, you can remove the Mono.defer and invoke it, and your call will be blocked, it needs the `defer` and `subscribeOn`

Comment: How does this differ from a much simpler approach with `Mono.fromCallable()`?
`Mono.fromCallable(() -> SECURE_RANDOM.ints(...)).doOnEach(...).subscribeOn(...).subscribe(...)`

Comment: with fromCallable it is also valid, I would be able to process it in another Scheduler. with defer he receives a publisher as a parameter, You can test the application above by looking at the behavior, with a simple change.

Comment: I would say that doing expensive calculations on assembly time is an anti-pattern, so don't see any benefits from `defer()` here, and we're back to square one :)